# in VS, Ctrl K + D is too troublesome. what are the alternatives?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, formatting

i love the Ctrl + K + D in visual studio to format our XML code but its too troublesome. In Netbeans we can do it with 1 hand (Alt + Shift + F). So I was wondering what other alternatives do we have to format code (or auto format as i type!)

Basically the only requirement i need is that i can do it with 1 hand or less.

Comment: Do you need to do it so frequently it matters?

Comment: Does Ctrl+K Ctrl-D work with xml?

Comment: actually yes, it adds up. i'm always looking for better ways to do things.

Comment: And you should be able to customize the hotkeys in VS. My friend bound `Format Document` from Ctrl+K Ctrl-D to a single key.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Heys the Ctrl-D is originally mapped to `Edit.GoToFindCombo` do you have any idea what it does.. (to be sure before i replace it..)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily set your own shortcut for the Edit.FormatDocument command:

- Go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard
- Type "FormatD" in "Show commands containiner" until it shows "Edit.FormatDocument".
- In "Press shortcut keys" choose whatever you want, e.g. Alt-Shift-F (which isn't used by default as far as I can tell)
- Click Assign.

Comment: Ctrl-E-D? It's Ctrl-K-D for me(at least with C#, no idea about xml)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Both seem to work for me, but under the Edit menu, in Advanced, it's *showing* as Ctrl-E Ctrl-D.

Comment: Interesting. For me it's showing `Ctrl-K Ctrl-D` and that's the only one working(VS2010 without plugins).

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Ah... maybe ReSharper reassigned them. Will edit.

Comment: for some reason Alt-Shift-F will open up `Menu - File` but Alt-F is working properly.

Answer (score 6):

In VS, Open Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard, find 'Edit.FormatDocument', assign it any shortcut you want.

Comment: cool btw have you got any idea how do we set it to format as we are typing?

Comment: @Pacenier, autoident (after pressing enter) and intellisense (if VS can fetch schema info) are working. But I don't know if VS knows any other formatting tricks. But you can write an extension for it. ;)